# Obtener localStorage de cliente en node js

Tags: jquery, angularjs, nodejs

Lo que sucede es que estoy haciendo una aplicacion con Node js, Angular y jQuery, y con sockets, lo que necesito es saber si el usuario se salio de la aplicacion, me emita un socket el cual me elimina de la lista de usuarios conectados, el usuario que se salio, llevo el siguiente codigo y solo me esta obteniendo es el id del usuario que primero se logueo, asi me loguee desde otro pc o un celular.

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
 console.log('Nuevo usuario conectado');
 io.emit('userconect');
 socket.on("disconnect", function () {
  io.emit('removeuser');
 });
});

y en el archivo js, tengo los sockets de esta manera:

socket.on('userconect', function () {
 var iduser = localStorage.getItem('el id del usuario');
 var userlist = $('.usersconects .users ul li[id=' + iduser + ']');
 if (userlist.length <= 0) {
  $('.usersconects .users ul').prepend('<li id="' + iduser + '"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> Usuario prueba</li>');
  }
});
socket.on('removeuser', function () {
 var iduser = localStorage.getItem('el id del usuario');
 var userlist = $('.usersconects .users ul li[id=' + iduser + ']');
 if (userlist.length > 0) {
  userlist.remove();
 }
});
```

Sera que hay alguna forma de obtenes por el socket el id del usuario almacenado desde el localStorage del cliente, y enviarselo al archivo js?

Agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: En el connect el cliente y el servidor deben negociar el ID (probablemente lo ponga o proponga el servidor). Luego al desconectare el cliente debe informar ese ID (salvo que haya una conexión permanente en cuyo caso el ID queda del lado del que sostiene la conexión y puede usar ese dato para actualizar la lista). De todos modos para evaluar mejor si te podemos ayudar quizá sea bueno que expliques lo que falta. Qué es io? qué es socket? cómo los obtuviste. Cada archivo js dónde está, en el cliente? en el servidor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es llevar el control del usuario que se conecta al servidor, y al desconectarse, enviarle ese id del usuario para actualizar tu lista, algo así:

*SERVIDOR*

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
var usuarioConectado = ""; // por cada socket conectado, guardara el id


 socket.on('login',function(id){
 usuarioConectado = id;// guarda el id, y cuando se desconecte enviara este id 

 console.log('Nuevo usuario conectado:'+usuarioConectado);
 io.emit('userconect', usuarioConectado);
});

 socket.on("disconnect", function () {
  io.emit('removeuser', usuarioConectado);
 });
});
```

*WEB*

```
//inicia y envia el usuario al servidor, para que comunique a los demas
//clientes, que este cliente se acaba de conectar con este id
socket.emit('login',localStorage.getItem('el id del usuario'));

socket.on('userconect', function (idUsuarioConectado) {
 //agregar a tu lista local,  el nuevo usuario conectado

});
socket.on('removeuser', function (idUsuarioDesconectado) {
 //remover el usuario con id idUsuarioDesconectado
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes agregar un escuchador de desconexion y basandote del id del socket elimines la persona, has la prueba agregando el siguiente codigo y veras que cada socket es diferente, de esta forma podrias hacer la eliminacion de usuarios.

```
  socket.on('disconnect', (data)=>{
    console.log(socket.id);
  });
```